# access <div> from javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

how can i access div element from javascript. i am doing the code in asp.net.
i want to make the div visible after clicking on a button.

the visibility code is given as follows:

i am getting an error :

> BC30451: 'data1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Javascript

```
var div = document.getElementById("<%=data1.ClientID %>");
div.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

Aspx

```
<div  id="data1" class="division" style="visibility: hidden">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `runat=server` and you can do it the way you have posted.

```
<div  id="data1" class="division" style="visibility: hidden" runat="server">
</div>
```

Comment: Its becoming visible only for a second. how can i make visible permanently?

Comment: What are you doing with `data1` in the code behind?

Comment: it contains just a section to display. and no code is written behind.

Comment: Try using `display:none` and `display:block` instead of visibility

Comment: This is a different issue, post a new question and include all of the relevant code.